# Qt files are too big.

Tags: c++, qt, dll, static, executable

After having searched and tried for hours, I could not get how to statically link the libraries to my exe. 
So I tried to copy the dependencies into the exe folder. 
I made a test program that changed the label on the click of a button. 
That was 14 mb. 
what should I do ?
I am using
icudt51.dll
icuin51.dll
icuuc51.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets

Comment: you can't link statically to a .dll, do you mean you linked dynamically in the end?

Comment: Be aware that to link statically with Qt libraries, your code has to be licensed under either the GPL or LGPL, or you have to pay a commercial Qt license. If your code doesn't meet one of those conditions you are not allowed to link statically with Qt.

Comment: Yes, Qt files are big!

Comment: What have you tried to link statically? (You'll need to build itself with the -static flag)

Comment: I don't know how to do -static. 
where should I add that? 
I am absolutely new.

Comment: user2670775: You need to download the Qt sources and compile Qt from source. Here are some docs: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-5-from-Git

Comment: @syam: That's not true. Commercial code, even statically linked, is fine with LGPL as long as the customer can re-link it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing I see possible is to use upx to compress your executable. You won't even notice the difference. It decompresses and executes your program so fast.

http://upx.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

There are many solutions to your problem:

1- Use Qt 4.8.5, there is not much difference between Qt 5 and Qt 4.8. It will help you because Qt 4.8.5 is not compiled with default support for QtWebkits, which means no dependency on  icudt51.dll icuin51.dll icuuc51.dll files.

2- If you wish to use Qt 5, you will need to recompile it with webkit disabled, that will also get you rid of above dependencies.
For details check this:
[post](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23210/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link Qt 5.1.1 statically as-is (without 3rd party patches), it only works for the in-source builds. Shadow static builds fail due to a bug in zlib cloning. A upx-ed simple executable that only uses widgets  will be under 5mb, more like 3mb. It's in the same ballpark for Qt 5 and Qt 4. I'm compiling both statically using MSVC2012 and it works just fine. Those are full static builds, meaning that Qt library is static and the C/C++ runtime is static as well. The only dependencies are on system DLLs. Makes life easy for everyone, although the release build can take a few minutes and *forget* about building on a 32 bit system.

The startup times of staticly-built executables are amazing. It's pretty much instantaneous :)